# react.js How do you create pagination?

Tags: reactjs

I am making pagination with react.
I found the logic below.
I have a few questions that I don't understand.

1. Where is the **n** used as `setPageBlock`and `setCurrentIndex` parameter defined?
2. How can I prevent pageBlock from going to -1?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const dump = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "dum1",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "dum2",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "dum3",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "dum4",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "dum5",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "dum6",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    title: "dum7",
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    title: "dum8",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    title: "dum9",
  },
];

export default function PaginationContainer() {
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [pageBlock, setPageBlock] = useState(0);
  let firstPage = pageBlock * 4;
  let pages = dump.slice(firstPage, firstPage + 4);

  const onClickPageItem = (id) => {
    setCurrentIndex(id);
  };

  const onClickPage = (type) => {
    if (type === "prev") {
      if (currentIndex <= 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (currentIndex - 1 <= 4 * pageBlock) {
          setPageBlock((n) => n - 1);
        }
        setCurrentIndex((n) => n - 1);
      }
    } else {
      if (currentIndex >= dump.length) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (4 * (pageBlock + 1) <= currentIndex + 1) {
          setPageBlock((n) => n + 1);
        }
        setCurrentIndex((n) => n + 1);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>pagination test</div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: "24px" }}>current Indx: {currentIndex}</div>
      <div style={{ fontSize: "24px" }}>current page block: {pageBlock}</div>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: "15px" }} onClick={() => onClickPage("prev")}>
        prev
      </div>
      {pages.map((data, index) => (
        <div onClick={() => onClickPageItem(data.id)} key={data.id}>
          {data.title}:{index}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div style={{ marginTop: "15px" }} onClick={() => onClickPage("next")}>
        next
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called an arrow function and n is the parameter for that arrow function.
You should first read about arrow functions then you will understand what's happening.